# Access and use the values of the accelerometer in the Android kernel level

Tags: android, linux-kernel, accelerometer

How can I access the accelerometer in the android kernel space and use it's data? I'm working on a project where I need to control some of the phone's functionality while the phone is moving (in a car) and I want to use the accelerometer to help determine if the phone had accelerated. It has to all be done in the kernel space. I found on the android developer pages how to use the accelerometer and the SensorEvent to detect changes in a user level application. But how to do something like that on the kernel level? Should I make a system call?

From looking around a bit and searching, I think the files are in /goldfish/drivers/hwmon/ but I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accelerometer input, at the antive level, is taken from */dev/input/event* devices. You can verify that using the toolbox's `getevent()`, which will show you the input events in real time as you tilt the phone (if memory serves, you need */dev/input/event3* but you can check this for yourself easily).

The drivers for the accelerometer export this character device, which in turn the Android runtime (with the assistance of *libhardware*) later converts to the familiar SensorEvent. There is no kernel API for this. Your simplest solution would be to interface with the */dev/event directly*. This could be done in two ways:

1. User mode daemon listens on */dev/event*, and also communicates with your kernel thread (e.g. by blocking on another character device which your kernel module exports, reverse system call, etc)
2. not recommended but would work - opening the */dev/input/event* from kernel mode (using a direct call to `sys_open` and then calls to `sys_read`). This would require "working around" kernel protections (most notably `KERNEL_DS` being set).

Comment: It sounds like you really know what you're talking about; unfortunately, I don't. I'm really a newbie when it comes to both linux and android in general. Firstly, as I've mentioned in my original post, it has to be fully in the kernel mode, so I guess option A isn't what I need. 
I have no idea what toolbox you mean. But what I get from what you said is that I need to have the device connected to test the events. So I can't check which event is it on the computer? Would you please try to explain in a noob way? (^_^)

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.. This is is what we do for a living :-) The answer was techie because you asked about kernel mode, so naturally it was assumed. "toolbox" provides the shell commands you get on Android with "adb". Start by running "getevent" (And looking on the Android developer website). This will show you how your device sends the accel. events. Then, you get the device name, and you can use option (B), by calling sys_open, sys_read from kernel mode - as it already probably documented elsewhere on this site. If not, simply add comment here

Comment: I see how it could be assumed so. I should've been clearer I guess. 
I'm afraid I still don't get how can I check for the sensorevent (getevent) using the emulator.